# Complex Matrices Hermitian and Positive-Definite Intuition/Visualisation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

When dealing with $\Bbb{R}$ it is easy to visualise matrices as how they 'distort' space - I am wondering if, when dealing with $\Bbb{C}$ there is also a geometric way of visualising these matrices, or at least some sort of intuition behind them besides how the linear transformation acts on the basis. Specifically, what is the intuition/geometric visualisation behind a *hermitian* matrix and a *positive definite* matrix (e.g. an orthogonal matrix geometrically represents rotation/reflection/etc.). Cheers.

Comment: The fact that Hermitian matrices can be diagonalized into a real diagonal matrix by a unitary matrix gives some intuition. In particular, this says there's always an orthogonal basis with real eigenvalues ... So we know our space decomposes into a direct sum of orthogonal subspaces in such a way that the Hermitian operator scales each summand by some real number.